# Intellij IDEA 15: Debug button does not open the debug pannel

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After upgrading to IDEA 15, when I press debug button, debug panel does not open automatically.

I searched whether there is a setting to open debug panel automatically, but couldn't find any.

Does anyone know how to get the debug window open when debug button is pressed?

Comment: Works for me -- osx, 15.0.1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has been fixed in IDEA 15.0.2